# delete single row in dataset in power BI through app

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I want to delete a specific row in the table in dataset . Can I do this through app or have to do it manually only. Because we can delete all rows of table but not single . Why so?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete a single row in a Power BI query, unless it is the first or the last row of the query result, in which case you can use the "Delete Row" command.

You may want to use sorting to expose that row as the first/last row in the data set.

If you want to delete a row in the middle of the data set, you can create a filter that excludes that row from the query, but you would need to specify the conditions for the filter to match that particular row.

Comment: This means as dataset has "datasetID" and Table has "tableID"  , But Rows doesn't have any "rowID"??

Comment: That depends on your data source. If it has a RowID column, then, sure, you can filter out the row with a specific ID.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems to be quite sufficient to use the "Remove alternative rows" function from the remove rows option then modify it to your own end.

For example, I've got 30 rows but want to remove row two.
First Row to remove:
2
Number of rows to remove:
1
Number of rows to keep:
29

This removed just row 2 so it seems to work if you just want to remove one row.

Answer (score 2):

I got the idea from here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Delete-only-2-particular-rows/m-p/249275#M110551.
... fiddled a bit and ended up with this:

in the query editor, click on  "Advanced Editor".
…which will show all applied steps up to the last one, e.g.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("D:\LTE_FBP.xlsm"), null, true),
    cap_Sheet = Source{[Item="cap",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(cap_Sheet,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, …, {"Column941", type any}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",3),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Top Rows",22),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows1" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Bottom Rows",1)
in
    #"Removed Bottom Rows1"
```

enhance this by removing only row 2

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("D:\_Ulm\# ECE Data Analyst\Power BI\LTE_eNB_Feature_Build_Plan 960051.xlsm"), null, true),
    cap_Sheet = Source{[Item="cap",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(cap_Sheet,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, …, {"Column941", type any}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",3),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Top Rows",22),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows1" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Bottom Rows",1),
    #"Remove Row 2 only" = Table.RemoveRows(#"Removed Bottom Rows1",1,1)
in
    #"Remove Row 2 only"
```

then enhance this by removing rows 2 and 3 (of what's left after the previous step)

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook( File.Contents("D:\_Ulm\# ECE Data Analyst\Power BI\LTE_eNB_Feature_Build_Plan 960051.xlsm"), null, true),
    cap_Sheet = Source{[Item="cap", Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(cap_Sheet,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, …, {"Column941", type any}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",3),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Top Rows",22),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows1" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Bottom Rows",1),
    #"Remove Row 2 only" = Table.RemoveRows(#"Removed Bottom Rows1",1,1),
    #"Remove Row 3and4" = Table.RemoveRows(#"Remove Row 2 only",1,2)
in
    #"Remove Row 3and4"
```

So, in command Table.RemoveRows

- the 1st parameter is the reference to the previous step name
- the 2nd parameter is the absolute row number of what's left after all previous steps => as row 2 was to be deleted and parameter is 1 it's obvious that the row counting starts with 0
- the 3rd parameter is the number of rows to be removed

I'm just at the beginning of Power BI and I'm not sure whether to love it or to hate it ;-)

Have fun!